# Azure Devops Cant Run xUnit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, xunit

I have an ASP.Net Core Web API application with unit tests built using xUnit. I am currently using the .Net Core 2.1.4 SDK and have the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` nuget package installed in both the Web API and xUnit project. I am able to build and run the Web API and the tests just fine on my local machine.

The application builds just fine in Azure Devops, however I cannot get the tests to run.

I am running the tests on Azure Devops using the Dotnet `Test` command. I have the step configured like so:

[image: Test configuration]

After the step sucessfully builds the tests project, I get the error:

`The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', version '2.1.4' was not found. Test Run Aborted`

Additionally the console tells me the following versions of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` are installed:

`2.1.0`
`2.1.1`
`2.1.2`

Do I need to set something up in Azure Devops that specifies which version of .Net Core my project requires? If that is the case, why is the Web API/test project able to build even though they require 2.1.4?

Answer (score 1):

Try by run it as "Visual Studio Test" instead and in the "Test files" box add two rows for xUnit.

```
**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*test*.dll
!**\obj\**

!**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll
!**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll
```

It's working good for me.

[image]

Otherwise take a look on Shinigami'a tutorial in: https://blog.bitscry.com/2019/03/21/running-xunit-tests-in-azure-devops/
but his "Test files" paths did not work for me.